# How can i fix my previous week code so it works properly

Tags: php, html

Here is my code where am facing the problem

Here am saving the current week number in one variable $week

```
<?php
    $week=date('W')-1
?>
```

Here am posting that week number in url so that by decreasing the posted $week number am trying to get the previous week

```
<td width="120" height="70" align="center" style="border-bottom:1px dashed #000000; border-top:1px dashed #000000;">
    <h1 style="color:#000000;"/>
    <a href="ex2.php?week=<?=$week-1?>">
        <img src="../images/previous_week.jpg" width="91" height="44" border="0" />
    </a>
</td>
```

The problem with the below code is.....

It is working properly upto march 1st week but it is not working to get the previous week from march it is showing the unix timestamp that is jan 1st 1970...

---

Here is the code to get the previous week dates from the posted week number

```
<?php
include ('class.php');
if(!isset($_GET['week']))
{
    $count = $obj->getD();

    if(date('N') == $count)
    {

        $prior_week = date('W') - 1;
        if($prior_week == 0)
        {

            $prior_week = 52;
            $year = date('Y') - 1;
        } else
            $year = date('Y');

            echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($year.'W'.$prior_week.'1'));
            echo " (MON)~ ";
            echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($year.'W'.$prior_week.'7'));
            echo " (SUN) ";
        }
    } else{

        $count = $obj->getD();
        $week=$_GET['week'];

        if($week>=0)
        {
            if(date('N') == $count)
            {
                $prior_week = $week- 1;
                if($prior_week == 0)
                {
                    $prior_week = 52;
                    $year = date('Y') - 1;
                }
                else
                   $year = date('Y');

            echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime(date('Y').'W'.$prior_week.'1'));
            echo " (MON)~ ";
            echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime(date('Y').'W'.$prior_week.'7'));
            echo " (SUN) ";
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: There are wrong if else statements curly braces are in wrong places

Comment: no they are in correct position

Comment: it is working from current week that is week number 24 to weeknumber 11(04-03-2013 (MON)~ 10-03-2013 (SUN)) but if i click again previous week the number is decresed to 10 n it is printing(01-01-1970 (MON)~ 01-01-1970 (SUN) )

Comment: @mounika, you either have a missing opening curly bracket or an extra closing one (see first else)

Comment: Agree with @Pete, first `else` part needs `else{`

Comment: no na.... I checked it thoroughly they are fine I didn't placed any extra brace to it....

Comment: if i wont place3 brace then it takes only one statement na....and i need only one statement to check... so i didn't placed the braces over htere

Comment: Then you need to remove `echo " (SUN) ";    }` extra curly brace

Comment: agree with Pete, there is no bracket in first else

Comment: sorry about previous statement, the code looks fine i checked it in my editor and everything's fine, found the problem, but cernunnos answered it... but try to well format your code use this kind of method -> if() //something here else //something there (when there is only one line of code), but generally use if(){//something here}else{something there}, you'll see that the code is more readable for you and others who may need to correct it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the date format you are passing to strtotime.

When number is 10 you subtract 1 and end up doing:

```
date("Y-m-d",strtotime("2013W91"));
```

when in fact what you wanted to do is:

```
date("Y-m-d",strtotime("2013W091"));
```

Just make sure you pad any week numbers less than 10 with a 0

```
// ...
if ($prior_week < 10) {
  $prior_week = "0".$prior_week;
}
echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime(date('Y').'W'.$prior_week.'1'));
```

Comment: else if($week==10){
        echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime("2013W091"));
         echo " (MON)~ ";
        echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime("2013W097"));
          echo " (SUN) ";
     }

Comment: if i use the above code(date("Y-m-d",strtotime("2013W091"));) it is working for week=10 properly but for week=9 it is printing the same 01/01/1970 if i use the code given by you that is if ($prior_week < 10) {
  $prior_week = "0".$prior_week;
}
echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime(date('Y').'W'.$prior_week.'1'));

Comment: No problem :) the answer said you should pad (or prefix) the week number with a 0, not fix it at "09", im sure you understood that already though.